# phpinfo() does not display stats extension

Tags: php, apache, statistics

I am trying to install PECL stats extension on my local xampp system. Unfortunately I am not successful. I have copied the `php_stats.dll` to `xampp/php/ext`.

Then I have added the line `extension=stats` on my local `php.ini` file.
When I restart Apache, phpinfo doesn't displays the extension stats.

System:

```
Win 10,
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.2.32 
PHP Version 7.2.32
```

Comment: Restart the webserver and look again.

Comment: Improved formatting and fixed minor spelling